# DI and generic classes in dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm trying to create a generic class from the object graph in Dagger.
Taking the Coffee machine example, is there any pattern to create a generic CoffeeApp class?

```
CoffeeApp<String>
```

for example...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Generic types can only be obtained through object injection (field or constructor) and not through `get()`.

Your example is a bit odd because a generic `CoffeeApp` doesn't make much sense. You can certainly `@Provide` a generic type and `@Inject` a generic type, however.

Comment: It is indeed a weird scenario. My purpose is injecting a different NetworkInterface classes - One which actually submit requests and a mock class for testing. These classes reside in a generic class (that inherits from AsyncTask - in Android)